# Convert string to array of integers in golang

Tags: go

I am looking for an answer in internet but it no one that fit my needs.

I have a string in the following format:

```
"[2,15,23]"
```

and i am trying to convert it in this format:

```
[2,15,23]
```

I need the type after the convertion to change to []int. I need to convert it because i want to use it later to make an interface type to use it in a sql query as param.

Is there any way to convert it?

Thanks

Comment: You can use basic JSON unmarshalling here.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better way using `json.Unmarshal`:

```
func main() {
    str := "[2,15,23]"
    var ints []int
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &ints)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", ints)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example if you haven't figured it out based on the comments suggesting that you use [json.Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/t42PPlZXZX)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    str := "[2,15,23]"
    ints, err := convertToIntSlice(str)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", ints)
}

type IntSlice struct {
    Ints []int
}

func convertToIntSlice(s string) ([]int, error) {
    a := &IntSlice{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"Ints":`+s+"}"), a)
    return a.Ints, err
}
```

Comment: You don't need all this overhead of declaring a type, you can Unmarshal directly in an int slice: https://play.golang.org/p/3VgfnPo7Hz

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly hackish but you could treat it like a csv:

```
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "strings"
)

in := `"[2,15,23]"`
r := csv.NewReader(strings.NewReader(in))

records, err := r.ReadAll()
```

Comment: ReadAll() returns [][]string, not []int as asked. Additional conversion from string to int is required.